# Magento add limit to product collection

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to show last 150 added products.

I'm creating the module and add in xml

```
  <reference name="content">
        <!-- Add product list to content -->
        <block type="newprod/product_list"     name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">

            <!-- Add toolbar to product list -->
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <!-- Add pager to toolbar -->
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>

            <!-- Specify toolbar block name -->
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                <name>product_list_toolbar</name>
            </action>

            <!-- Use custom product collection -->
            <action method="setCollection">
                <value helper="newprod/getProductCollection" />

            </action>

            <!-- Use custom available sort by orders -->
            <action method="setAvailableOrders">
                <value helper="newprod/getAvailableOrders" />
            </action>

            <!-- Set the default sort by order -->
            <action method="setSortBy">
                <value>price</value>
            </action>

            <!-- Set default direction to ascending -->
            <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                <value>asc</value>
            </action>

            <action method="setColumnCount">
                <column>12</column>
            </action>
      <action method="setLimit"><limit>50</limit></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

in getProductCollection

```
 public function getProductCollection()
   {
   $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
  ->addStoreFilter($store_id)
  ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
  ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)  
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))                          
  ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
  ->setPage(1, 9);
return $collection;
}
```

but in result page I get `n` items on page and it's fine, but pager render for all 10000 products, how can I limit this? I'm trying to play with `_beforeToHtml()` function from  `mycomp_NewProd_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` but now luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add

```
->setPageSize(150)
```

before return collection.